# Need Help Sql Server current date query

Tags: sql-server, excel, pentaho

I need help in coming up with a query that counts the total amount of rows for the current date. I need this to update everyday on its own with the current date. I am using Pentaho to run a job everyday with the total row count but i am having difficulties coming up with a query for it. This query below gives me the current date but my count is coming up with 0. I know i have rows there for today so not sure why its at 0.

```
    SELECT dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0) as 
    Received_Date2,COUNT(*) as Enrollments_Completed
    FROM CCMDB.dbo.InboundCorrespondenceDetails CD, 
    CCMDB.dbo.ResolutionLetterDetails RD 
    WHERE CD.ccid = RD.ccid
    and ReceivedDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    AND ReceivedDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
    AND CatID in('cat0014')
    AND IncomingType <> 'RITS'
    AND status = 'Completed'
```

Comment: No need for date arithmetic. In fact it will harm performance. If `ReceivedDate` is a `date` you can use `where ReceivedDate=getdate()` directly. If it's a `datetime` you can use `cast(ReveivedDate as date)=getdate()`. SQL Server will convert that to a range query between the start and end of the day, taking advantage of any indexes that cover `ReceivedDate`. That' something you can't do with other types

Comment: You really should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins We probably need to see some sample data to really be able to help. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thank you i broke it down to just having in the select field : convert(date, getdate()),COUNT(*) as Enrollments_Completed and then in  WHERE ReceivedDate = getdate(). I am still getting a count of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your date range is lesser than the current date (dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)). so basically, you are trying to retrieve previous day records.

if you need records for the current date then:

```
SELECT dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0) as 
Received_Date2,COUNT(*) as Enrollments_Completed
FROM CCMDB.dbo.InboundCorrespondenceDetails CD, 
CCMDB.dbo.ResolutionLetterDetails RD 
WHERE CD.ccid = RD.ccid
and ReceivedDate >= DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()),0)
AND ReceivedDate < DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()+ 1),0)
AND CatID in('cat0014')
AND IncomingType <> 'RITS'
AND status = 'Completed'
```

Comment: thank you Vinay. Would this give me records for the whole day? like sum? im only getting a few records with this query. I believe its giving me real time count . I need the total row count for the day.

Comment: Im not sure why with that query i am only getting a count of applications that have been "completed" that day instead of a TOTAL count received that day.

Comment: If you run the above query (i.e., today), it will give you the real-time count if records are actively being filled in to that table. If you run it towards the day closure. You will the get the entire count.

For some reason, if records are already filled-in ahead for the day then you should get the total count. If you want to get the previous day record then you earlier query works fine or you can modify this as well.(also, please double-check other filters in your where clause)

Comment: the query above is giving me a 0 count